# How to separate four bytes of floats?

Tags: c#

Could anyone, please guide me as how to separate 4 bytes of float in Visual Studio C#, and retrieve each byte as a character? As I need to save each byte of float as hex value in a text (`.hex`) file.

Regards
Asad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class to convert from float to a byte array.

Comment: I am using this code,

fubar = 25;
byte[] data1 = new byte[4];
data1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(ltof.fubar);


But the output is (MSB)65 200 0 0(LSB).

I am supposing the output is not the equvilant of 25.Plz guide!

Comment: That's correct.  The IEEE 754 encoding of 25.0f is: 65 200 0 0

Comment: Thankyou Matt Greer and Detmar!
You helped in solving my big problem!

Comment: @Asad, please select this answer as correct, by clicking the tick on the left hand side of it.